# Fatal error: Call to a member function unique() on null

Tags: php, html, laravel, tags

When i try to apply coupon i got this error and i'm not the creator of the script i'm just using it i need help to run it

This the code

```
    private function validate_coupon_from_db($parts){
        $parts = $parts->unique('code');
        $model_codes  = $parts->pluck('code')->all();
        $existing_part = Part::whereIn('code',$model_codes)->where('date', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('code')->get();//->where('date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(2))->get();

        if($existing_part->count() < $parts->count()){
            return [
                'status' => 100,
            ];
        }else{

            //$part_not_valid = $existing_part->where('date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(2))->all();
            $part_not_valid = $existing_part->filter(function ($item) {
                return strtotime($item->date) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+2 hours')));
            });

            if($part_not_valid->count() > 0){
                $part_not_valid =$part_not_valid->all();
                $string = '';
                 foreach ($part_not_valid as $part){
                     $string .= '<br><hr><span> '.$part->code .' '. $part->part_one_name .' - '. $part->part_two_name .' </span>';
                 }

                return [
                    'status' => 0,
                    'data' =>
                        '<div id="s_w_PC_cCoupon_pnlMsgIns" class="divCouponError" style="background-image:url(//static.planetwin365.com/App_Themes/PlanetWin365/Images/ErrorTypes/Errors.png);">'.
                            '<span id="s_w_PC_cCoupon_errMsgIns"><span>Les côtes suivantes ne sont plus disponibles:</span>'. $string .'</div>'
                ];
            }
            else{
                return [
                    'status' => 1,
                ];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error i got

> ERROR:
>   Symfony\Compo
>       nent\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Call to a member function
>        unique() on null

Comment: The $parts variable is comming null

Comment: Check `$parts` before calling `validate_coupon_from_db()`. Apparently you're sending null instead of a Collection object which it expects.

Comment: how i can do that can you rewrite the code as i should

Answer (score 0):

First return $parts after the first line in the function validate_coupon_from_db() to check whether $parts has some value or null.

I think its is null, so you cannot run unique() on a null, you should only run unique() on a object.